# Counting "Unique" combinations ( subsets ) of a set of numbers

Tags: combinations

Is there a formula for a possible number of permutations of a set of numbers that returns all unique outcomes for example:

[1,2]=(1,2) (as (2,1)==(1,2))

[1,2,3]= (1,2),(1,3),(2,3) (as (3,1)==(1,3) etc)

such that the order is not important so that instead of n! combinations, we have 3 rather than 6 for the 2nd example?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be selecting subsets of size 2 from sets of size $n$ so the number of subsets is 
$$n \choose 2$$ which is read "n choose 2". It is a binomial coefficient. There are other notations for it.

For your first example this would be $2 \choose 2$ and ${3}\choose{2} $ for your second example.

However, if you want to know the total number of subsets then it is
$$2^n$$ where again $n$ is the size of your set.

EDIT:

I don't write Matlab but to do it by hand in Python, for subsets of size 2:

`x = [1,2,3]
for i in range(len(x)):
    j = i + 1
    while j < len(x):
        print(x[i], x[j])
        j += 1`

with output

(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)

Comment: Thankyou. This is interesting for some code i am writing (matlab). For the second example, we know that there are 6 total combinations but 3 in my subset. Is there a way to export the three subset values, i.e. a matrix such as :
M=[1,2; 1,3; 2,3]

Comment: @R.Smith I updated my answer which you should be able to port to Matlab. I would also use 'subset' instead of 'total combination'.